# Proof for "A sequence tends to infinity if, as n increases, $a_n$ increases without bound. Formulate a precise definition."

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This is the full question:
[image: Question]

My attempt at solving this is:
Precise definition: To say that $\{n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ tends to infinity is to say that $\frac{1}{n}$ gets closer to zero as n gets closer to $\infty$.
Proof: Let $\epsilon \gt 0$. We pick an $n\gt\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, so $\frac{1}{n}\lt\epsilon$. For all $m \ge n, \frac{1}{m} \le \frac{1}{n} \lt \epsilon$ which proves $\frac{1}{n}$ gets closer to zero.

The second sequence follows the precise definition, but I have confusion about the proof.
My attempt: Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $n \gt \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, so $\frac{1}{n} \lt \epsilon$. For all $m \ge n, \frac{1}{2^m} \lt \frac {1}{m} \le \frac {1}{n} \lt \epsilon$, which proves $\frac{1}{2^n}$ tends to zero.

My question is, is the way I made the precise definition correct, if not, how to make it? Is there any source I should read?
Secondly, is my second proof correct? If not, what would be the correct proof?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: "formulate a precise definition of this notion" means to state the notion in full generality, not for particular examples. (So you should talk only about an unspecified $a_n$.)

Comment: Your primary job is not to prove anything, instead it is to **write a definition**. Only then do you apply the definition that you wrote, to prove that the two given examples do fulfil the definition.

Comment: @LeeMosher how should I write a definition? Can you provide me a source where I can learn these things? If I saw a solution to a similar problem I could understand, or maybe solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good attempt at a definition, but it unfortunately oversees an important requirement of your sequence. You say that your sequence is increasing if the reciprocals of the terms of the sequence get closer and closer to $0$. Now, consider the following sequence:
$$9,9.9,9.99,9.999,\ldots$$
The reciprocals of the terms are:
$$\frac{1}{9},\frac{10}{99},\frac{100}{999},\frac{1000}{9999},\ldots$$
You can see that all of these reciprocals get smaller  (and hence closer to $0$). But, they have the values:
$$0.111111\ldots , 0.101010\ldots , 0.100100 \ldots , \ldots$$
None of these reciprocals are going to be less than $0.1$. Basically, no term in your original sequence is greater than $10$. So, your sequence does increase, but **with bound**.

To ensure your sequence increases without bound, you must not only ensure that your sequence increases, but your sequence must increase such that it can get **arbitrarily large**. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first precise definition is that you're saying $n$ tends to infinity if $n$ gets closer to infinity. This isn't particularly useful.

The usual way we define a limit as being infinite is by altering the $\epsilon$ definition of a limit. We say a sequence $(a_n)$ tends to infinity if for all $M$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have that $a_n\geq M$. Clearly this holds for the sequence given by $a_n=n$ as we can take $N=M$.

In the case of the sequence $a_n=2^n$ we could again take $N=M$ as $2^n\geq n$ for all $n\geq0$.

Comment: I didn't say "n tends to infinity if n gets closer to infinity", I said (1/n)  tends to zero if n gets closer to infinity

Comment: Yes, your reasoning was $S=\{n\}$ tends to infinity (if $(1/n)$ tends to 0) as $n$ gets closer to infinity. To say that S tends to infinity if "statement" when $n$ tends to infinity has given yourself an argument which requires $n$ to go to infinity for $n$ to go to infinity.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very useful answer. All of the answers here are useful. I accepted Haran's answer because that one helped me to understand your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The informal definition is wrong because

- there are non-increasing sequences that do tend to infinity, and
- there are sequences that do not tend to infinity though they are unbounded above.

A correct definition is that taking a bound as large as you want, you can find a tail of the sequence that stays above it (i.e. some $a_n$ and *all* following elements).

$$\forall m:\exists n:\forall k\ge n:a_k\ge m.$$

Sequence $n$:

With $n=m$,
$$\forall m:\forall k\ge m:a_k=k\ge m.$$

Sequence $2^n$:

Also with $n=m$,

$$\forall m:\forall k\ge m:a_k=2^k\ge m.$$

Comment: Could you give an example of a sequence which is unbounded and increasing but doesn't tend to infinity?

Comment: I believe he meant that a sequence which is unbounded need not tend to infinity.

Comment: @CSquared: "increasing without bound" should be understood as "unbounded, but not necessarily growing".

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok. thanks for clarifying

Comment: @TonyK: in the first paragraph, I am not trying to be formal and don't use *universal* terms. The informal definition is wrong anyway, or too restrictive.

Comment: @TonyK: I think I answered that.